# How wherePivot() actually works internally in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-5.1

How wherePivot() actually works internally in laravel 5 ?

For Example I was practicing by watching a tutorial and the teacher was using wherePivot() for construing relationship:

```
public function friendsOfMine(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('Chatty\Models\User','friends','user_id','friend_id');
}

public function friendOf(){

  return $this->belongsToMany('Chatty\Models\User','friends','friend_id','user_id');

}

public function friends(){

  return $this->friendsOfMine()->wherePivot('accepted',true)->get()->merge($this->friendOf()->wherePivot('accepted',true)->get());

}
```

Comment: Did you check the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2dc84427005c9525426169476e8965bcfc7fd9bb/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L111)?

Comment: The `wherePivot()` method allows you to constrain a column (i.e. `accepted`) on the pivot table (i.e. `friends`), thereby selecting only those foreign records that match the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Thanks Guys .. but I think i found my answer*

A pivot table is a database table that only exists to serve a many-to-many relationship. Say you have a table “customer” and a table “drinks”. If you want to know which customer ordered which drink you have to create a pivot table customer_drinks(customer_id, drink_id).

**Define Pivot table**

```
class Customer extends \Eloquent {    
    public function drinks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Drink', 'customer_drinks', 'customer_id', 'drink_id');
    }
}
```

**Create a Record**

```
$customer = Customer::find($customer_id);
$customer->drinks()->attach($drink_id); //this executes the insert-query
```

**Remove record from pivot Table**

```
$customer = Customer::find($customer_id);
$customer->drinks()->detach($drink_id); //this executes the delete-query on the pivot table
```